# Convert text input to int or double depending on input

Tags: java, jtextfield

I have a JFrame where I am taking the input from a text field and converting it to an Integer.
I would also like to convert it to a double if it is a double and maybe return a message if it is neither a int or double. how can i do this?

My current code:

```
 int textToInt = Integer.parseInt(textField[0].getText());
```

Comment: parsing and catching exception ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String text = textField[0].getText();
try {
    int textToInt = Integer.parseInt(text);
    ...
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    try {
        double textToDouble = Double.parseDouble(text);
        ...
    } catch (NumberFormatException e2) {
        // message?
    }
}
```

To keep the precision, immediately parse to BigDecimal.
This parseDouble of course is not locale specific.

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    int textToInt = Integer.parseInt(textField[0].getText());
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    try {
        double textToDouble = Double.parseDouble(textField[0].getText());
    } catch(NumberFormatException e2) {
        System.out.println("This isn't an int or a double";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean isInt = false;
boolean isDouble = false;
int textToInt = -1;
double textToDouble = 0.0;

try {
    textToInt = Integer.parseInt(textField[0].getText());
    isInt = true;
} catch(NumberFormatException e){
    // nothing to do here
}

if(!isInt){
    try {
        textToDouble = Double.parseDouble(textField[0].getText());
        isDouble = true;
    } catch(NumberFormatException e){
        // nothing to do here
    }
}

if(isInt){
 // use the textToInt
}

if(isDouble){
 // use the textToDouble
}
if(!isInt && !isDouble){
// you throw an error maybe ?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the string contains a decimal point.

```
if(textField[0].getText().contains(".")) 
    // convert to double 
else 
    // convert to integer
```

No exception throwing necessary.

Before doing the above, you can check if the string is a number using regular expressions. One way is with the pattern `[0-9]+(\.[0-9]){0,1}` . I'm not the best with regex so please correct me if this is wrong.

Comment: So "foo.bar" is a valid double?

Comment: I realized and was editing my answer as you posted your comment :)

Comment: Better, but what about 1000 digits? Double has a maximum, and minimum representable values.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It really is easier to just throw and catch a NumberFormatException... I tried :(

Answer (score 0):

You could try a series of nested try-catches:

```
String input = textField[0].getText();
try {
    int textToInt = Integer.parseInt(input);
    // if execution reaches this line, it's an int
} catch (NumberFormatException ignore) {
    try {
        double textToDouble = Double.parseDouble(input);
        // if execution reaches this line, it's a double
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // if execution reaches this line, it's neither int nor double
    }
}
```